# Why a vertical electric coil experience a vertical force in a vertical magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I can't figure out the force acting on a coil in a magnetic field.

Suppose I have a coil with direct current running in it. We know this is an electrical magnet, which means when I put it in a big static magnetic field which points vertically, it will be pulled upward or downward.

However, if we analyze a differential element of the wire, we find that whichever direction it points to, the tangent vector together with the magnetic field vector forms a vertical plane which is tangent to the coil cylinder. Then if we use $\operatorname{d}\!\mathbf{F}=I \, \mathbf{B} \times \operatorname{d}\!\mathbf{L}$, the cross product would yield a force perpendicular to the tangent plane of the coil cylinder. This force will only act the coil toward or away from the center horizontally, making its diameter larger or smaller, instead of acting vertically like it were a magnet as in real life.

I believe my argument in the second paragraph is wrong because it contradicts the reality. But where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption that an electromagnet placed in a uniform magnetic field will undergo center of mass motion is incorrect.

Consider you place a small electromagnet, which we treat as a magnetic dipole, inside a large solenoid.  The static field inside the big solenoid can be assumed spatially uniform.

The force on a magnetic dipole in an external field is: $\vec{F} = (\vec{\mu} \cdot \vec{\nabla}) \vec{B}$, where $\vec{\mu}$ is the magnetic moment of the dipole. Thus, if the field is spatially uniform, the gradient of $\vec{B}$ is zero and the force is zero.  A dipole in a uniform external field can experience a torque and rotate about its center of mass axis if its magnetic moment isn't aligned with the external field, but it will not experience an acceleration in any one spatial direction like you suggest.

Thus, given the geometry of your system, we do not expect the electromagnet to move.  In order to get the behavior you expect, we would have to place the electromagnet in the solenoid's fringe field at the top or bottom where $\nabla \vec{B} \neq 0$.

Comment: Great answer! What is the equation $\vec{F} = (\vec{\mu}\cdot\vec{\nabla})\vec{B}$ called? What theorem or law of physics should I refer to?

Comment: @Neo you can search up "force on a magnetic dipole in an external field" There isn't really an official name for this formula